# Is there a way to send data to a SQL server in a private vnet using stream analytics jobs?

Tags: azure, azure-stream-analytics, vnet

As mentioned in the title, I am have set up a sql server in a private vnet which only can access the azure app service. Is there a way to send data to the SQL server using a Stream Analytics Job while still maintaining the private connection?

Answer (score 0):

**Is there a way to send data to the SQL server using a Stream Analytics Job while still maintaining the private connection?**

Yes, we can establish a connection with SQL Server with Stream Analytics via a private connection by allowing couple of ports.Tried to replicate the same "SQL server in a private vnet using stream analytics jobs."

**Step1:**
Created a new sqlserver with private Vnet connectivity

[image]

[image]

**Step2:**
Establish connectivity with SQL Database which is on vnet

[image]

here we go
[image]

i have found one reference [tutorial](https://hub.packtpub.com/azure-stream-analytics-7-reasons-to-choose/)

if any connectivity issue refer this [tutorial](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-sql/database/private-endpoint-overview?view=azuresql#how-to-set-up-private-link-for-azure-sql-database)

Comment: Does it work if the sql server is the output? I can't seem to get a connection if the sql server is the output